# TextField text hides when typing

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

When i am typing in textfield.some times textfield internal part moves up when i am typing and text is visible when focus removed from textfield. Its occur some times but when it occurs then all textfield of my apps behave like this. Any solution to remove this bug?. No steps found to reproduce this bug. it occur randomly while using in Iphone.

Comment: Post your code for the better understanding...